# Convert double 0,10 to string with preserving 0 after last digit or convert double to string the way it is

Tags: c#, powershell

I am struggling with conversion double to string. Digit contains 0 that disappears once you evaluate variable. I've already tried tostring('##.00') but it doesn't work for all cases. For example, if value has only two digit diveded by . tostring('##.00') method will add additional 0 at the end. See example below

```
$d = (1.1).ToString('##.00') # Results in 1.10

$d = (1.10).ToString('##.00') # Results in 1.10
```

Please advise how to convert double to string preserving all digits including 0 if it exists.

Comment: `1.1` and `1.10` are numerically the same thing, and `double`s do not store decimal but binary digits. The only .NET type that preserves decimal digits is `decimal`, which in PowerShell is declared with the `d` suffix (`1.10d.ToString()`). That said, using strings to begin with if you need a specific decimal representation of a number is a better idea (converting it when calculations need to happen).

Comment: Maybe just use `decimal` instead? try `1.1M` vs `1.10M`; but the `0` placeholder in `ToString` means *always show a digit here*... so: you're kinda forcing things here; perhaps `0#` ? although I think `#` only works this way for significant digits; however, simply `0.1M.ToString()` vs `0.10M.ToString()` works the way you specify

Comment: I think the question would be easier to answer with some background. I.e. *why* do you want to preserve digits? How does it fit into the overall system?

Answer (score 0):

as @Marc Gravell said above, mask ##.00 forces to show 2 digits after decimal separator. If you don't want to add insignificant zeroes to your result string, try to use ##.## as mask:

```
PS L:\> echo (1.1).ToString('##.##') 
1,1
PS L:\> echo (1.10).ToString('##.##') 
1,1
```

the last example was explained by Jeroen above - the numbers 1.1 and 1.10 are equal, so if you want to differentiate between those (for any non-mathematical reason) - then you need to define clear rules/cases when 1.1 should not be equal 1.10.